# Tool in Linux which divides the screen into two halves

Tags: linux, zoom, linux-mint

Is there a tool in Linux which divides the screen into two halves allowing to zoom windows not only to the whole screen but also to those halves? Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean "zoom"?

Comment: One of three buttons in the top left (for apple) or right (for everything else) corner of a resizable window.

Comment: You mean Maximize..  
Anyway, have a look at dwm - http://dwm.suckless.org/..